# ntheorem counters and sub-counters without any section divisions

Tags: environments, counters, ntheorem

I'm writing an academic article response memo in LaTeX and would like to create counters for each reviewer and sub-counters for each of their comments, e.g.:

**Reviewer 1.1 (Problem X)**: *Reviewer comment verbatim*

*Response*: Our response to the problem above.

**Reviewer 1.2 (Problem Y)**: *Reviewer comment verbatim*

*Response*: Our response to the problem above.

*[Here I would increment counter]*

**Reviewer 2.1 (Problem X)**: *Reviewer comment verbatim*

*Response*: Our response to the problem above.

I've seen some questions about how to use ntheorem when using sections without numbering, but would it be possible to create environments to produce an output similar to that above without having any section divisions at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: Why do you rule out "section divisions"? The reason I ask is that I believe that by far the easiest solution would involve employing (bespoke) section and subsection counters.

Comment: I just thought it would look unattractive and confusing since some reviewers only had one or two comments and the others had multiple ones. But based on what I’ve read, I may try to find a way to make it work with sections since, as you wrote, it seems much easier.